# Selenium - click the second prompt with same ID

Tags: selenium

I have a complex HTML like the below.There are at least two elements with `data-automation-id='promptIcon'` attribute. In Selenium IDE `//*[@data-automation-id='promptIcon']/` selected the first occurrence (i.e. next to the label Category). Now I would like to click/select the second element with `data-automation-id='promptIcon'` attribute (next to the label Owner). How best to accomplish this?

```
<div class="GB-VO1SBAIJ">
 <div class="GB-VO1SBNHJ" style="left: 0%;">
  <div id="wd-EditPage-1$4296" class="GB-VO1SBOXH GB-VO1SBHXH GB-VO1SBJXH GB-VO1SBJN">
   <div class="GB-VO1SBBYH">
    <div class="GB-VO1SBJN" id="wd-PageContent-6$8263">
     <div class="GB-VO1SBAJH">
      <div class="GB-VO1SBIIH">
       <div id="wd-Panel-6$8269" data-automation-id="panel" class="GB-VO1SBF1J GB-VO1SBJN">
        <div class="gwt-Label GB-VO1SBJ1J GB-VO1SBI1J">
        </div>
        <div class="GB-VO1SBH1J">
         <div class="GB-VO1SBAJH GB-VO1SBG1J">
          <ul role="presentation" class="GB-VO1SBNHH GB-VO1SBGIH">
           <li role="presentation" class="GB-VO1SBDHH GB-VO1SBJIH">
            <div class="GB-VO1SBFHH">
             <label data-automation-id="formLabel" id="15$20858--uid318-formLabel">Category<span class="gwt-InlineLabel GB-VO1SBDIH"> Required</span>
             </label>
             <div aria-hidden="true" class="GB-VO1SBGHH wd-5b94a643-7d98-473f-b3a4-be58aaf8d4f5">Category</div>
            </div>
            <div class="GB-VO1SBHHH">
             <div aria-labelledby="15$20858--uid318-formLabel" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="-2" id="15$20858--uid318" data-automation-id="responsiveMonikerInput" class="GB-VO1SBCFL GB-VO1SBJN GB-VO1SBIEL GB-VO1SBPFL GB-VO1SBNFL">
              <div class="GB-VO1SBHFL">
               <ul data-automation-id="selectedItemList" role="list" class="GB-VO1SBJUI GB-VO1SBOUI GB-VO1SBGFL" tabindex="-2">
                <li class="GB-VO1SBNUI">
                 <div id="-uid331" role="menuitem" tabindex="-2" class="GB-VO1SBFUI GB-VO1SBMUI">
                  <div data-automation-id="selectedItem_2200$2" class="GB-VO1SBDVH">
                   <ul role="presentation" class="GB-VO1SBFUH GB-VO1SBLUH">
                    <li class="GB-VO1SBCVH">
                     <i title="Clear Value" class="GB-VO1SBCIF GB-VO1SBJ1I GB-VO1SBB1I GB-VO1SBHUH" data-automation-id="DELETE_charm" role="presentation" data-icon-rtl-id="" data-icon-id="">
                     </i>
                    </li>
                   </ul>
                   <div title="Common" data-automation-label="Common" data-automation-id="promptOption" class="gwt-Label GB-VO1SBEVH">Common</div>
                   <ul class="GB-VO1SBFUH">
                   </ul>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                </li>
                <li class="GB-VO1SBNUI">
                 <div id="-uid332" role="menuitem" tabindex="-2" class="GB-VO1SBFUI GB-VO1SBMUI">
                  <div data-automation-id="selectedItem_2200$3" class="GB-VO1SBDVH">
                   <ul role="presentation" class="GB-VO1SBFUH GB-VO1SBLUH">
                    <li class="GB-VO1SBCVH">
                     <i title="Clear Value" class="GB-VO1SBCIF GB-VO1SBJ1I GB-VO1SBB1I GB-VO1SBHUH" data-automation-id="DELETE_charm" role="presentation" data-icon-rtl-id="" data-icon-id="">
                     </i>
                    </li>
                   </ul>
                   <div title="Absence" data-automation-label="Absence" data-automation-id="promptOption" class="gwt-Label GB-VO1SBEVH">Absence</div>
                   <ul class="GB-VO1SBFUH">
                   </ul>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                </li>
               </ul>
              </div>
              <span tabindex="0" data-automation-id="promptIcon" title="Prompt" class="GB-VO1SBBGL">
              <i class="GB-VO1SBCIF GB-VO1SBCGL" data-automation-id="icon" role="presentation" data-icon-rtl-id="" data-icon-id="">
              </i>
              </span>
              <div aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0" style="display: none;" class="GB-VO1SBP3I" role="button" data-automation-morelinkexpanded="false" data-automation-id="wd-MoreLink">
               <img alt="" draggable="false" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="gwt-Image GB-VO1SBPII GB-VO1SBB4I">
               <span title="More (-3)" class="GB-VO1SBC4I">More (-3)</span>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </li>
           <li role="presentation" class="GB-VO1SBDHH">
            <div class="GB-VO1SBFHH">
             <label data-automation-id="formLabel" id="15$26787--uid319-formLabel">Owner</label>
             <div aria-hidden="true" class="GB-VO1SBGHH wd-5b94a643-7d98-473f-b3a4-be58aaf8d4f5">Owner</div>
            </div>
            <div class="GB-VO1SBHHH">
             <div aria-labelledby="15$26787--uid319-formLabel" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="-2" id="15$26787--uid319" data-automation-id="responsiveMonikerInput" class="GB-VO1SBCFL GB-VO1SBJEL GB-VO1SBJN GB-VO1SBIEL">
              <div class="GB-VO1SBHFL">
               <ul data-automation-id="selectedItemList" role="menu" class="GB-VO1SBJUI GB-VO1SBGFL GB-VO1SBOUI" tabindex="-2">
               </ul>
              </div>
              <span tabindex="0" data-automation-id="promptIcon" title="Prompt" class="GB-VO1SBBGL">
              <i class="GB-VO1SBCIF GB-VO1SBCGL" data-automation-id="icon" role="presentation" data-icon-rtl-id="" data-icon-id="">
              </i>
              </span>
             </div>
            </div>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="GB-VO1SBIYH">
   </div>
   <footer class="GB-VO1SBCYH">
    <div>
     <div data-automation-id="toolbarSupportingWidgetsContainer" class="GB-VO1SBOOE GB-VO1SBAOE">
      <div class="GB-VO1SBLNE">
       <div class="GB-VO1SBMNE">
        <div class="GB-VO1SBCOE">
        </div>
        <div class="GB-VO1SBPOE">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div>
       <div class="gwt-Label GB-VO1SBDNE">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="GB-VO1SBCPE GB-VO1SBEPE">
     </div>
    </div>
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XPath, there is a easy way to do it:

```
//*[@data-automation-id='promptIcon'][2]
```

Explaining:

> **//*[@data-automation-id='promptIcon']**
>
> It is your actual xpath, will select any html tag that has a attr named "data-automation-id" with the exactly value "promptIcon".
>
> **[2]**
>
> The element node that you want to select. if you put [5], XPath will try to select the 5° result in this html, based in what note you're calling it.

Comment: I hit the error - Element //*[@data-automation-id='promptIcon'][2]/ not found, However index 1 works fine Element //*[@data-automation-id='promptIcon'][1]/

Comment: If you try `//*[contains(@data-automation-id, 'prompt')][2]` returns the same error?

Comment: Hi Striter, this works - //*[contains(@data-automation-id, 'promptIcon')][1] . However this still do not work //*[contains(@data-automation-id, 'promptIcon')][2]

Comment: but you can found both using Chrome console command `$x("//*[contains(@data-automation-id, 'promptIcon')]")`?